# Django forms field not required asterix still there when shouldnt

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm with two fields that shouldnt be required.

One of them is defined with a `null=True` and a `blank=True`.

The other one is a checkbox with a widget `required=False`

My model

```
user_id = models.CharField('Genium360 member #', max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

My form

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ...
    fields = ...

    widgets = {
        'communications': CheckboxInput(attrs={'required': 'false'}),
    }
```

My template

```
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="Soumettre"/>
            </form>
```

I can send the for form without filling these two fields, but the required asterix (*) still show in the form.

How can I remove it.

I'm lost on why it still show.

Thanks.

Comment: You show the model `user_id` field but not the `communications` field. What is it? Is a boolean field?

Comment: @guillermochamorro yeah, NullBooleanField with a null and blank at true.

Answer (score 0):

Try `attrs={'required': False})` i.e. the Python boolean syntax.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#widget